# Can't post JSON with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

When trying to `POST` some JSON data using Retrofit `2.0.0-beta4`, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class my.pojos.Credentials

...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate RequestBody converter for class my.pojos.Credentials.
Tried:
* retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
* retrofit2.GsonConverterFactory
  at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextRequestBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:288)
...
```

Not sure what's going on here. As far as I know, my setup is following other presumably working examples verbatim.

My app-level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
  ...
}
```

And my retrofit builder:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(context.getString(R.string.rest_url))
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**

My API interface looks like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.*;

public interface MyRestApi {
    @POST("/auth")
    Call<Auth> login(@Body Credentials user);
}
```

And the API call:

```
Call<Auth> authCall = retrofit.create(MyRestApi.class).login(creds);

authCall.enqueue(new Callback<Auth>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<Auth> call, Response<Auth> response) {
         ...
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<Auth> call, Throwable t) {
         ...
     }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like my problem was that I had `beta3` of the gson converter in my `build.gradle`, but `beta4` of retrofit. Changing my `build.gradle` to the following made things work:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of today

These are the dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
```

Do check here for latest version
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.retrofit2%7Cconverter-gson%7C2.0.1%7Cjar